# writing text to an image in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to write text I've converted from an image to an ascii art into a different image, but for some reason I keep getting strange shapes and not the letters (in english) the were converted.

Here is the result of my function so far:

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with the font.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def saveTxtAsPicute(file_path, width, height, currentframe):
    """
    converts txt file to picture then saves it
    :param file: txt file to convert
    :return: the filtered ascii image
    """

    # Open text file and read content
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
       text = file.read()

    # Define image size and font size
    font_size = 14

    # Create new image
    img = np.zeros((int(height), int(width), 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    img.fill(255)

    # Set font and get text size
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    text_width, text_height = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_size, 2)[0]

    # Calculate number of columns and rows
    cols = int(width / font_size)
    rows = int(text_height / font_size)

    # Draw text on image
    x = y = 0
    for i in range(len(text)):
        cv2.putText(img, text[i], (x, y+font_size), font, font_size/2, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        x += font_size
        if x >= width:
            x = 0
            y += font_size

    # Save image
    cv2.imwrite('./txtFilesPic/text_image' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg', img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are in the right direction however there are few things you should keep in mind
1- The default font used by cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX is not monospaced. Which means, every character does not take equal width, some characters like 'i' can take less space whereas others like 'k' can take more. Thus if you increase your starting x position by the same value at each iteration, it would look something like this
[image]

To avoid this type of spacing, you can use monospace fonts like roberto mono etc
2- The font size does not translate exactly into pixel values. For example, a font size of 12 will not necessarily be 12 pixels in the image. Thus if u just increase the scale with which u are increasing the x and y in each iteration, your image should look a lot cleaner

```
def saveTxtAsPicute(file_path, width, height ):
    """
    converts txt file to picture then saves it
    :param file: txt file to convert
    :return: the filtered ascii image
    """

    # Open text file and read content
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
       text = file.read()

    # Define image size and font size
    font_size = 2

    # Create new image
    img = np.zeros((int(height), int(width), 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    img.fill(255)

    # Set font and get text size
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    text_width, text_height = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_size, 2)[0]

    # Calculate number of columns and rows
    #cols = int(width / font_size)
    #rows = int(text_height / font_size)

    text =text.strip()
    print (text)
    # Draw text on image
    x = y = 0
    y = 80
    for i in range(len(text)):
        cv2.putText(img, text[i], (x,y+6*font_size), font, font_size, (0, 0, 0))
        x += font_size*19
        if x >= width:
            x = 0
            y += 25*font_size

    # Save image
    cv2.imwrite('./text_image' + '.jpg', img)

saveTxtAsPicute('./foo.txt',100,500)
```

This code with "hit it up" as the text in the file would give you the following output
[image]

Comment: thank you for your comment but I still have the same issue as shown in the picture, with the code you wrote :( is there any way in which I can fix that??

Comment: so my code when run at your end, with the same input as mine, is not generating the image i attached in my answer ?

Comment: through one computer it does, for the other one it does not for some reason

Comment: another related question, is there a way for me to make the font smaller than 1, I want it to be as small as possible.

Comment: i am not sure if that is possible, one hack could be to create a much larger image - like say 4096x4096 and then once you have the text on it, resize the entire image(with added text) to the desired resolution

Comment: of course `putText()` will accept font sizes less than 1.0. why not simply try it?